# nodemon server.js is executing in vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

[Running] node "c:\Programing\WEB DEV\M.E.R.N\App clone Projects\Tinder clone\tinder-backend\server.js"
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'c:\Programing\WEB DEV\M.E.R.N\App clone Projects\Tinder clone\tinder-backend\dbCard.js' imported from c:\Programing\WEB DEV\M.E.R.N\App clone Projects\Tinder clone\tinder-backend\server.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:10)
at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:89:40)
at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:242:28)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.326 seconds

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your module exported from `dbCard.js` cannot be found, hence the `[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]` error. Could you provide us more information, like your file structure, the `dbCard.js` and `server.js`.